# Unable to Deserialize Object using Newton Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, getjson

I tried with following code but getting error for input parameter as string.

```
protected override object DeserializeCore(Type type, byte[] value)
{
     using (var ms = new MemoryStream(value))
     using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
     {
          var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sr, type);
          return result;
     }
}
```

and I passed it as `sr.ToString()` getting error :

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: you should get string from streamreader and check what is in it

Comment: getting compile time error only

Comment: This code is not the cause of that exception (which is runtime, not compile-time), the input is. Show your input. It's invalid JSON.

Comment: with ` var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sr, type);` i'm unable to execute and compile , how can i check for input parameter :(

Comment: @Neo you should give us this string not pass it to deserialize object

Comment: use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd(), type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this not be simpler?

```
    protected override object DeserializeCore(Type type, byte[] value) {
        var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, type);
    }
```

(I can't figure out why you are using the streams. Is it related to some issue with the encoding?)

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
public class JsonObject
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

var s = "{'Value':{'something':'test'},'Type':'JsonData'}";
var o = DeserializeCore(typeof(JsonObject), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s.ToCharArray()));
```

should work fine.